# .net core 3.1 inserting CommandManager-class into class library-project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, class-library

I'm currently on trying out to migrate an MVVM-library I've created a few years ago from .NET 4.5 to .NET Core 3.1. 
That went surprisingly good, but at the moment I'm struggling with the CommandManager-Class that I use in my RelayCommand-Class.

I'm using the CommandManager for the CanExecute Eventhandler of my RelayCommand-Class:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Properties
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
    {

    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

During my research on that problem I've found out, that the System.Windows.Input is not part of.NET Core. There are many Solutions that recommend to switch the Projecttarget from Classlibrary to WPF-Application or embedding the PresentationCore-Assembly.

These Solutions didn't work for me - mostly I guess because of my usage of a normal .NET Core Classlibrary Project.

So i wanted to ask if their is a similar class existing inside of .NET Core?
Or would it be better if I try to code my own CommandManager-Class to replace it?

Currently the last option would be to extract the Commanding-part out of my library and put it directly into the project that uses the library (an avalonia client application).
But that doesn't feel right...

Kind regards

GeoCoder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `.csproj` file to this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Hello RBasniak, thanks for your reply. :) I tried to change the Sdk of my project to WindowsDesktop:
`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>`

But that doesn't work. 
I'm planing to use the library in a .net core-Application that should be running on Windows and Linux, so I'm not sure if changing the SDK will be a good idea if i want multi-plattform support?

Comment: Did you include `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`?
But I don't think the classes under System.Windows namespace should be used on multiplatform library, that's why they're not in the .NET Core, they only work on Windows.

Comment: Aahh!  `<UseWPF>true<UseWPF>` - that's what I've overseen. Now it works. 
Ok, thanks for the explanation - so my thoughts were right that it's not a good idea to use Windows-specific Classes in .NET Core-Applications. 

So i guess the only Solution to this now would be to write an own commandmanager-class specificly based only on .netCore-Components right?

Comment: If this solved the problem in the question, would you mind accepting my answer? :) Thanks!